# Calling default prop function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that has a default prop

```
Component.defaultProps = {
  waitForResolve: defaultFunction
}
```

This `defaultFunction` accepts an `event` as an argument and returns an array of objects dragged into browser. After that at some point the component has a Promise that waits for this function to resolve and proceeds with other manipulations.

While this code works(I import `importedFunction`) I can't figure out how to make it work for default function so I get the same results but without providing any other function other than default one.

```
import {importedFunction} from 'some-package'

<Component
   waitForResolve={evt =>
     importedFunction(evt).then(files => files.map(({ file, ...rest }) => file))
   }
>
   <p>Try dropping a folder here.</p>
</Component>
```

I need something like above code but swapping `importedFunction` for the `defaultFunction`

Thanks for help!

Comment: How you define `defaultFunction` in `<Component/>`?

Comment: I use the `Promise.Resolve(defaultFunction(event)).then....` inside other function of `<Component/>`

Comment: but how `defaultFunction` is defined? defaultProps only assings reference to this function - where is body?

Comment: Assuming `importedFunction` and `defaultFunction` are defined in `some-package`, can't you just do `import { importedFunction, defaultFunction } from 'some-package'`?

Comment: you should use `this.props.waitForResolve` in both cases

Comment: Let me try again. I have this function in utils folder and import it in the `<Component/>` file, after that I assign it as a default prop. In several places in `<Component/>` this function is called as `this.props.waitForResolve` but I think as it is event based I can not just pass it like `<Component waitForResolve/>` so it would pick up the default function. I think something like `<Component waitForResolve={evt=>defaultFunction....}>` shall be used, but it is not working

Comment: In simple words I just need to call that default prop function but in the same context in which I call one in the example

Comment: No, defaultProps lets you defining default `this.props.waitForResolve` (f.e. using `defaultFunction`) inside `<Component/>` and gives possibility to overwrite it by another function when needed (by passing as prop).

Comment: Thanks, I will try to look more throughly on the problem again but anyways thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { importedFunction } from 'some-package';

const defaultFunction = evt => importedFunction(evt).then(files => files.map(({ file, ...rest }) => file));

export default class Component extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    waitForResolve: defaultFunction
  }

  render() {
    return <input onChange={this.props.waitForResolve} type="file" />;
  }
}
```

Simple usage:

```
<Component />
```